# How to define Environment variables in aws EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, environment-variables, amazon-eks

I'm new to k8s and I was looking for a way to define environment variables in my Aws EKS deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass environment variable to Pod's container not deployment.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        env:
        - name: MY_VAT
          value: MY_VALUE
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/